# 以故 at the beginning of the sentence

Tags: translation, classical-chinese

I am wondering if the following translation is correct?

**以故**使炳夏搜送刊行文集，則歸報以不得，極可歎也。

This (以故) caused 炳夏搜 to pursue publication of the collected essays, thus there will be no payback, which is extremely pitiful.

(EDIT) Here is the sentence in a context:

...此文若出，必有一場紛紜，以增斯文之厄，不是小事也。再昨招宋炳夏商量, 又更審其祖考所撰行狀，則記先老爺雅言，以為孔子之後集群儒而大成者，朱子也。其功多於孟子云云。若於大學，果有如言者之說，則其雅言豈有如此之理耶。以故使炳夏搜送刊行文集，則歸報以不得，極可歎也。

The passage comes from a letter by Korean Conffucian 宋時烈.

Comment: The text is inadequate for people to figure out what was going on (來龍去脈). As a minimum, please post the paragraph that contains this sentence.

Comment: You are right, sorry about that. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以故使炳夏搜送刊行文集，

Expand the sentence:

[以此之故]**致使**(宋)炳夏**搜尋並遞送**刊行文集，[以此之故] = 源由於此 - 果有如言者之說，則其雅言豈有如此之理耶。